# Android app compability

Tags: android, sdk, version

I've build my app under the version 1.6, 2.1 and 2.2 of android and it works. I'd like to know when I'll publish it what is the best :

- Build under 1.6 and so it will be compatible with newer version of android

or

- Build under 2.2 and set "Target SDK version" to 8 and "Min SDK Version" to 4

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using anything that is specific to 2.1 or 2.2 there is no difference. If you for example use install to SD card feature of 2.2 you have to use Target SDK and min SDK option.

Comment: Thank you, I'll built under 2.2 then.

Answer (score 2):

Build it under 2.2 and use Min SDK Version.
Target Version is described as the following:

"With this attribute set, the application says that it is able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion), but was explicitly tested to work with the version specified here."

Actual statistics of the "market share" are available on the developer website:
http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

1.6 takes 20% at the moment.